# Accept Rate is dead, long live Reputation Leagues!

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues, user-card

Once upon a time there was accept rate; it was [introduced by Jeff](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) three and half years ago with a bright future and lots of potential. Lots of water flowed in the river since then and it turned out that feature is bringing more harm than good, until it was finally [removed from public display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/152859) not long ago.

Jeff already started a major discussion regarding [citizenship level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/152859) and how it will replace accept rate; but I'm not sure when it will come to bear fruit and what fruit that might be.

So what I suggest is simple and using existing data: bring the [Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/) forward by displaying the ranking in the user card instead of the good old accept rate. Unlike accept rate, it can't be abused or used in wrong ways. Low values will not attract any negative feedback and the Leagues are very nice system that currently doesn't really get enough attention in my opinion as users just don't know it exist.

And as always, rough sketch: (using random user but he's just a good model :))

> [image]

Comment: I'm not sure about this. What does it say about the user that the rep count doesn't say already? Does this more than stroke high-rep users' egos? Anyone with a bit of familiarity with the system knows roughly how to categorize a rep count on the spectrum which ranges from `1` to `Jon Skeet`. I'd much rather have a well-thought-through "citizenship" metric.

Comment: This basically the same as the reputation points

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's a measure of the reputation of one user compared to others. Nothing new or that can't be seen elsewhere, but so was accept rate isn't it?

Comment: Note that some sites have *opted out* from displaying league standings on user profiles.

Comment: @Martijn didn't know that. Yeah, this complicates things then. :/

Comment: What would you be trying to achieve with this number? It provides no useful signal beyond the raw reputation value, IMO.

Comment: +1 for **"...I'm not sure when it will come to bear fruit and what fruit that might be"**

Comment: OK, looks like I'm in minority here. Well, was worth trying!

Comment: The system is broken until people stop plus-1ing based on a phrase and their language tastes.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment sorry not sure I got what you mean... ?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd _'+1 for "...I'm not sure when it will come to bear fruit and what fruit that might be"'_ Ergh.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment this is Meta, it's not like +1000 or -1000 has any real effect anyway so don't take it hard. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you will come up with some formula that will calculate reputation with badges,

I hope if categorization done with TAGs then will be great so that users with skills can be automatically Leagued. :)

Nothing much to say on this, I am still new to say more :)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as reputation points, so I don't think it's good to add it. However a *tag* based implementation might be useful, e.g. if a user is in the top `X%` of that tag, then show this infomration, otherwise don't show anything. X might be around 30, so after the user is in the top 30% of that tag, then this information would show telling the others that this user is active in that particular tag. If a question has multiple tags then pick the one where the user is at the best position.

Comment: I disagree. Raw total of rep is different than ranking compared to other users. As for tag based ranking something similar [was already suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80123/152859) before.